# Position remaining forms after one is closed without flickering

Tags: c#, wpf, forms

I want to create some sort of popups. I have designed a form (TestFenstr). When an event is raised a new TestFenstr is created, saved in a list and populated. The forms are created under the last form.

[image: Pic of sample forms]

When i close one of the forms, the remaining forms under the deleted one should fill the hole. The closed event will fire an event, when it is closed. Then i change the location of the remaining forms with this code:

```
        int indexList = iList.IndexOf(this);
        int countList = iList.Count;


        for (int i = indexList; i < countList; i++)
        {
            var newLoc = (iList.IndexOf(iList[i]) - 1) * 65;
            iList[i].Top = newLoc;
        }

        iList.Remove(this);
```

The problem is that you can see some flickering when changing the location. Same with WPF. My question ist: Is there a better way doing this or how can I avoid this flickering.

Comment: Moving windows around is trickier than one might imagine. Is there a particular reason this is not just one window with a list in it?  You can size a window to content.

Comment: Thank you for you response. I have tried it a single form. There were some flickering at the bottom. Maybe I should try it with WPF.

Comment: I have a toast sample which animates each item as you add it and then animates them before removing several seconds later. Obviously not exactly what you're doing here but you might find it interesting. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31416.wpf-mvvm-friendly-user-notification.aspx#Toast

Comment: Hey Andy, thank you very much. Toast notification were the keywords i missed. I will look at your approach.